# predefined argument value to map function. Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var i = [1,2,3,4,6,7];
var k = i.map( (data, i) => { if(data==1) return 2; else return data; } );
console.log(k);
```

This program is going to output `[2,2,3,4,6,7]`

I am changing value of `k` based on a specific value. How can i change the value according to a specific array index using map function?

like how we do normally, `array[index] = somevalue;`

Comment: why do you need to iterate if you have already an index for changing?

Comment: Couldn't you just change `if(data==1)` to `if(i==1)`...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: If you are only changing a specific array index, just clone the array and then set that particular element. `k=i.slice(); k[index] = somevalue;`

Comment: `if(i ==1) …` ‽

Comment: `i[0] = 2` .....

Comment: well, i am changing the array value based on another value that i am getting from the dom nodes which is the index number. I want to use map function to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check with the index of the array while iterating, with the wanted index and return a selected value or the original value.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7],
    index = 3,
    result = array.map((a, i) => i === index ? 42 : a);

console.log(result);
```